# How to get response from server, that uses HTTPS (Windows phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm trying to get authentication token for google account using WebClient.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&service=writely&source=1C&Email=myemail@gmail.com&Passwd=mystrongpassword", UriKind.Absolute));
```

When client_OpenReadCompleted it throws Exception:

```
"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
```

What can I do to solve that problem if I know that URL request is 100% working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously the connection is opened, so it's not the https part that stops you. Something else that you are supplying isn't correct.

Comment: What it could be "something else"? Email and password are correct. Or maybe I have to modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send a POST command instead of a GET command for Google ClientLogin.
See link below to Google developers guide

[Using ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps#Using)

Comment: I have tried to use POST method as you suggested, but I got the same result '"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."'

Comment: what response do you get when you make the call using a REST browser plugin or curl? Does the URL return a response with a capta Url?